# How to get total of days Multidatepicker MDP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-multidatespicker

I using Multidatepicker MDP from [here](http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/).
I want to get the total days that selected by user, and place it into input text.

For example if the user select 2 days, then the total is 2.
And the total put in a input type text.

Here is my JS

```
$('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker({
     numberOfMonths: [1,2],
     altField: '#altField',
     minDate: 2,
});
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: How do you mean *total days*? You mean if someone selected 2 dates the total is 2 or is the total expected to be the days between them as a range? Could you add a specific example of what exactly would be selected and what exactly the expected output would be?

Comment: I mean, is user select 2 dates, then the total is 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the information from the site you linked:
http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/#demo-ui-calendar-methods

You can specify the `onSelect` method to respond to selections.
To get an array of selected dates you can use `$('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker('getDates')` as documented.

If you only care for the number of selected dates you can simply use the `.length` of the array.

I never worked with this component before but parsing together the info from the documentation the below seems to work. Adjust as needed.

```js
$('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker({
    numberOfMonths: [1, 2],
    altField: '#altField',
    minDate: 2,
    onSelect: function(){
      $('#numberSelected').val($('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker('getDates').length);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
<div>
<span>Number Of Days Selected</span>
<input id="numberSelected" type="text"/>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="mdp-demo"></div>
```